# Technique for integration of following forms

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

Recently, I've been facing a no. of problems that involve integral of the type:  $\int f(x)dx/f'(x)$ and also of the type $f(x)/√f'(x)$.
So, is there any special method for such type of questions?
One such question was $$\int (x+sinx) \frac1{cosx+1} $$
Clearly this is of the first type. I could make out that such questions must involve the use of integration by parts but I'm unable to apply that. It makes the problem more complex.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\space\text{d}x=\ln|f(x)|+\text{C}$$

If you want to use integration by parts, you'll get:

$$\int y(x)z'(x)\space\text{d}x=y(x)z(x)-\int y'(x)z(x)\space\text{d}x$$

So, set $y(x)=f(x)$ and $z'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{f'(x)}}$:

$$\int\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{f'(x)}}\space\text{d}x=f(x)\cdot\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{f'(x)}}\space\text{d}x-\int\left[f'(x)\cdot\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{f'(x)}}\space\text{d}x\right]\space\text{d}x$$

---

Now, notice for $\frac{x+\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$ that you cannot use (1) because:

$$\frac{x+\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}=\frac{x+\sin(x)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x+\sin(x)\right)}\ne\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x+\sin(x)\right)}{x+\sin(x)}$$

Comment: Thanks.I now tried the technique you mentioned and it made this problem way easy to solve. Just wanted to ask, will this work on all such type of integrals?

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal You're welcome. I'm glad that I could help. And yes of course it does, because you can get to this 'rule' without substituting a function for $f(x)$.